# Regex to make sure there is one and only one empty line after the last import in a JSX file

Tags: regex, jsx

I want to make sure that there is only one empty line after the last import in a JSX file.

These are possibilities in a JSX file:

1. No import at all
2. No import, yet empty space at the beginning of the file (including empty lines)
3. Empty line between imports
4. Default imports
5. Named imports
6. Multiple named imports
7. Default and named imports mixed
8. Space before imports
9. Multi-line imports
10. Multiple lines after the last import
11. Any code can come after the last import
12. No code after the last import

I have tried to create [a list of example files](https://github.com/MohammadMiras/RepoPossibilities) for this purpose.

I tried this Regular Expression, but it does not work for all of them:

```
import\s*\{?[^\}]*\}?\s*from\s*'[^']*'(?!\s*import)\n\n
```

I thought about using AST (abstract syntax tree), but that does not give me spaces. And it seems very hard to me.

What Regular Expression should I write to support this requirement, to make sure that there is one and only one empty line after the last import?

Comment: Why would you use regular expressions for this?

Comment: Do you intend to correct these files to "_one and only one blank line_" after the last import statement ?

Comment: @sln There is no joke. Regular expressions handle very simple grammars, but are insufficient for most languages. You want a parser based on a proper grammar. If you want a tired joke related to this topic, there's the popular Chtulhu answer about the perils of attempting to parse HTML with regular expressions. But for this simple problem, examining the file and finding the last occurrence of `import` and checking how many newlines follow is probably best done with a simple program in your language of choice.

Comment: @tripleee Since you mention HTML and regex, I'm sure you can explain how these different regex remove all html from complex web page.  https://regex101.com/r/FXfppF/1
https://regex101.com/r/p0t1H8/1
https://regex101.com/r/YOYd6R/1
https://regex101.com/r/QrbEwV/1

These regex were constructed from parts of my regex SAX parser and use the w3c standard regex definitions. Sounds like you have an issue when anybody dares to tamper with their own source code of any language. I actually use a very small regex to remove comments from any language. Thanks for your insight though.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/kU0avm/1

Comment: Only 2 kinds: Atomic https://regex101.com/r/p0t1H8/1 or LA Assertion https://regex101.com/r/43lFyV/1 and https://regex101.com/r/ji6uTn/1

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question,
You can match just the last import keyword and blindly match all the next
(optional) blank lines then replace with a double line break.

```
^([^\S\r\n]*import\s*\{[^\}]*\}\s*from\s*'[^']*')(?![\S\s]*?^\s*import)\s*^
```

replace with `$1\r\n\n\n`

https://regex101.com/r/x464x4/1

Evaluation   - Use Multi-line mode

```
^                             # begin of line
(                             # (1 start)
   [^\S\r\n]*                    # horizontal whitespace
   import \s*                    # import
   
   \{ [^\}]* \}                  #  { ... }
   
   \s* from \s*                  # from
   
   ' [^']* '                     # '..'
)                             # (1 end)
(?! [\S\s]*? ^ \s* import )   # assert not a 'import' ahead
\s* ^                         # get all wsp up to begin of line
```

You can even add a line after the last *import* at the end of file by  changing
`\s* ^` to `\s* (?:^|$)`

See https://regex101.com/r/XnWMIz/1